# String value = "clay" changing automatically to "/000lay"?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a C program out of the [Cows and Bulls game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) word version

Here's my code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char word[4],guess[4];
    int i,j,check=0,b=0,c=0,d[4];
    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to the Cows and Bulls game!\n\nEnter a 4 letter word to be guessed :- ");
    scanf("%s",word);
    while(check==0)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your guess :- ");
        scanf("%s",guess);
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(i==j && word[i]==guess[j])
                {
                    b++;
                    d[j]=j;
                    break;
                }
                else if(word[i]==guess[j] && j!=d[j])
                {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d cow(s) and %d bull(s)!\n",c,b);
        if(b==4)
        {
            printf("Congratulations! You have correctly guessed %s",word);
            check=1;
        }
        else
        {
            check=0;
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

But the problem I am having is suppose I put the word "clay" to be guessed but as soon as the compiler accepts the value for the guess word, the word "clay" given previously changes to "/000lay" which completely screws the program. I am able to see this while debugging.

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZXqM.png)

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [sig] another bean counter:)   Unless you are in a ram-poor embedded environment DONT declare tiny buffers for text. Just put [256] as a minimum.

Answer (score 5):

You do not reserve space for the NUL-terminator(`'\0'`) at the end, ultimately invoking Undefined Behavior via the `scanf` when the input is greater than or equal to 4 characters. Change

```
char word[4],guess[4];
```

to

```
char word[5], guess[5];
```

---

Other suggestions and remarks:

- `system` requires `stdlib.h`. Include it.
- `conio.h` (and `getch`) are non-standard.
- `void main()` is not a standard signature of `main`. Use `int main(void)` instead. You also need to add `return 0;` at the end of `main` (This is implicit in C99+)
- Instead of `scanf("%s",word);`, use

  ```
  if(1 != scanf("%4s", word)) /* Check if `scanf` is successful; The `4` prevents buffer overflows */
  {
      fputs("scanf for word failed; Exiting...", stderr)
      exit(-1);
  }
  ```

  and similarly for the `scanf` for `guess`.
- It is better to initialize all your variables.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, a GOD I SAY! Thank you so much :)

Comment: But why didnt it happen with the guess variable?

Comment: @MihirKandoi Undefined Behavior means anything could be the result. When UB strikes, you can't be sure of anything.

Comment: @MihirKandoi Are you using turboC IDE?

Comment: It looks like the `word` array resides straight after the `guess` array in memory and when you read in the guess word it writes the null terminator in the first byte of the `word` buffer.

Comment: @MihirKandoi, it looks like what happened here is that the system put `word` and `guess` right next to each other on the stack (four bytes each); then, when you input `guess`, it wrote the NUL terminator (the fifth byte) over the first byte of `word`.

Comment: @CoolGuy My college does, but people here say it is absolute trash so I use CodeBlocks but all my classmates use TurboC

Comment: @CoolGuy This is literally my first month in engineering so I have no idea what to do and what not, I am simply following my college :P

Comment: I would like to know though what is input buffer :P

Comment: @MihirKandoi Yes. TurboC is 25+ years old outdated IDE. You can figure this out by the looks of the IDE itself. Never use it. C has changed a lot since those ages. Code::Blocks, OTOH, is one of the best IDEs available. I recommend you stick with Code::Blocks itself.

Comment: @MihirKandoi Your college must be bad then, if it insists on using TurboC. I suggest you learn from a good up-to-date online tutorial and study the modern C.

Comment: @MihirKandoi The input buffer is a place where input is consumed. `scanf`, `getchar` etc read user input from here. Say you have `int n; scanf("%d", &n)` and you type `5` and press Enter. The shell, on seeing the `\n`, sends everything, including the newline character, to the input buffer and `scanf` consumes the `5`. The input buffer is also called the standard input stream or `stdin`.